# How do I extend /include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php in upgrade safe manner?

Tags: sugarcrm

How do I extend `/include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php` in upgrade safe manner?

Answer (score 2):

You could create `/custom/include/SeachForm/CustomSearchForm2.php` which extends SearchForm2 (the class name for SearchForm2) traditionally (e.g. `CustomSearchForm2 extends SearchForm`). The harder task is accessing your custom class at that point.

SearchForm is instantiated from `include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php` - in a couple of possible places: the protected method `getSearchForm2()` and [assumed] public method `prepareSearchForm()`.

So how do you extend view.list.php? That one's easier. For any module you'd like a custom list view, create a file at `/custom/modules/MyModule/views/view.list.php` and define it as `CustomMyModuleViewList extends ViewList`. Some modules already have their own ViewList (e.g. Accounts, Calls) so for those you'd want to extend their original extended ViewList, e.g. `CustomAccountsViewList extends AccountsViewList`.

So create your custom ViewList extension, copy-paste the methods you need to alter (prepareSearchForm and getSearchForm2) and adjust as needed to load in your custom SearchForm class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question relates to SugarCRM 6.5.x (and potentially earlier 6.x versions - I haven't checked), Matthew Poer's answer is exactly right except for one thing: the class to extend is called SearchForm instead of SearchForm2.  To do this:

- Copy include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php to custom/include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php
- Edit custom/include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php and edit the class declaration, changing it to:

  ```
  require_once('include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php');
  class CustomSearchForm extends SearchForm {
  ```
- Copy include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php to custom/include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php
- Edit custom/include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php and edit the class declaration, changing it to:

  ```
  require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php');
  class CustomViewList extends ViewList {
  ```
- In the function prepareSearchForm in the CustomViewList class, change the line

  ```
  require_once('include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php');
  ```

  to

  ```
  require_once('custom/include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php');
  ```

  and the line

  ```
  $searchMetaData = SearchForm::retrieveSearchDefs($this->module);
  ```

  to

  ```
  $searchMetaData = CustomSearchForm::retrieveSearchDefs($this->module);
  ```
- In the function getSearchForm2 in the CustomViewList class, change the line

  ```
  return new SearchForm($seed, $module, $action);
  ```

  to

  ```
  return new CustomSearchForm($seed, $module, $action);
  ```

The other functions of CustomSeachForm and CustomViewList can be subsequently overriden as needed.  If you have module-specific view.list.php files, you will, of course, need to change them to extend CustomViewList instead of ViewList.